# Executing the output as filename

Tags: bash, command-substitution, indirection, shellcheck, multiple-indirection

In one of my Bash scripts, there's a point where I have a variable `SCRIPT` which contains the `/path/to/an/exe`, and what the script ultimately needs to do, is executing that executable. Therefore the last line of the script is

```sh
$($SCRIPT)
```

so that `$SCRIPT` is expanded to `/path/to/an/exe`, and `$(/path/to/an/exe)` executes the executable.

However, running `shellcheck` on the script generates this error:

```
In setscreens.sh line 7:
$($SCRIPT)
^--------^ SC2091: Remove surrounding $() to avoid executing output.

For more information:
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2091 -- Remove surrounding $() to avoid e...
```

Is there a way I can rewrite that `$($SCRIPT)` in a more appropriate way? `eval` does not seem to be of much help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$($SCRIPT)` indeed does not do what you think it does.

The outer `$()` will execute any commands inside the parenthesis and execute the result string.

The inner `$SCRIPT` will expand to the value of the `SCRIPT` variable and execute this string while splitting words on spaces/

If you want to execute the command contained into the `SCRIPT` variable, you just write as an example:

```sh
SCRIPT='/bin/ls'
"$SCRIPT" # Will execute /bin/ls
```

Now if you also need to handle arguments with your `SCRIPT` variable command call:

```sh
SCRIPT='/bin/ls'
"$SCRIPT" -l # Will execute /bin/ls -l
```

To also store or build arguments dynamically, you'd need an array instead of a string variable.

Example:

```sh
SCRIPT=(/bin/ls -l)
"${SCRIPT[@]}" # Will execute /bin/ls -l

SCRIPT+=(/etc) # Add /etc to the array
"${SCRIPT[@]}" # Will execute /bin/ls -l /etc
```

Comment: The array cases should be `"${SCRIPT[@]}"`; "`$SCRIPT"` expands to only element [0].

Comment: I've just understood that I wrote a question other that the one I wanted to ask. I got lost in indirections. However this is the correct answer to the question I asked. [Here's the correct question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63660088/execute-command-that-results-from-execution-of-a-script-whose-name-is-in-a-varia).

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me with `sh -c`:

```
$ chrome="/opt/google/chrome/chrome" 
$ sh -c "$chrome"
Opening in existing browser session.
```

It also passed the [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

with bash, just use $SCRIPT:

```
cat <<'EOF' > test.sh
SCRIPT='echo aze rty'
$SCRIPT
EOF
bash test.sh
```

produce:

```
aze rty
```